# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy - External links

Tags: google-analytics, pagespeed, hotjar

I'm trying to boost my pagespeed score, and one of my major breaks is this:

Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy.

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] i know this is GTMetrix and non Pagespeed, pagespeed has problems today]

And all under it that are left are the facebook/hotjar/analytics scripts. I'm 100% sure that I can't tell my project manager 'well screw the analytics! I'm removing them!' so I have to manage with them.

I'm pretty sure I can't force them to have a better cache (the htaccess doesn't touch things that are not loaded from the server itself) so... what can I do to force them to have a harder cache and boost my pagespeed score?